# How to do Categories and SubCategories in Access with Forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've done a bit of research on how to order the database to deal with a hierarchy. 
Here's what I'm doing.

There are Companies that work on communication technology. That is what I'll call a general Technology. There are different types of Comm Tech, lets say RF and Laser. So there is a category, and two subcategories.

Take another category - Welding. Specific Types of welding could be plasma, and laser. So now I've got laser twice, but it belongs to two different categories. This will happen over and over with various main categories and subcategories.

I can make my peace with the variety of different options on how to arrange the table relationships. I am having trouble figuring out how to present this to users with forms.

There are two main user forms that have to be made, one for adding General Tech, Specific Tech, and the relationships between them. The second is the Form that shows the Company, and lets the user select MULTIPLE general technologies, along with the specific tech that goes along with each of those.

What I'm stumped on is how to allow (on the form) for N general technologies that are tied specifically to this company. I looked on the NorthField database, and thought that maybe the order details was the way to go, but wasn't sure.

Is there an example out there, or a design pattern, or something that I should be following to make these forms?

Thanks

Comment: Cascading combos? Microsoft Tree View control?

Comment: Thanks. Part of the problem when you are new is even learning the correct search terms. I've read the 'Bible' and didn't notice either of those in there. That gives me something to look for.

Comment: I would also consider using a single combobox. You can create hierarchy in combos by display things using `Top Level > Second Level` or even just "indenting" second level items using several hyphens. Cascading combos don't work well (or at all) in datasheet views and continuous forms so I like to stick with a design that can be utilized using only a single dropdown combobox.